# how to show numbers in edittext one after one in android?

Tags: android

i want to show numbers in `EditText` one after one not a random numbers like that so what is the perfect code to do this step ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private int random;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                random = random();
                edit.setText("text" + random); // want to show numbers one after one like 1,2,3,4,5 

            }

            // want to change this code to be able to show numbers one after one 
            public int random() {
                Random generator = new Random();

                int x = generator.nextInt(100);
                return x;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
 private int number=0;

 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              //  random = random();
                edit.setText("text" + number++); // want to show numbers one after one like 1,2,3,4,5 

            }
```

Comment: If this answer helped you , You should accept this as an answer by clicking on the tick mark below 0.